# Spells that belong to multiple schools

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, wizard

The new arcane elemental schools mention nothing about what spells belong to what schools. So in the case where a spell appears in both your elemental focus school and the opposition school, how are you to decide how to treat it?

[Sirocco](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sirocco) is a great example.

> School evocation [air, fire]; Elemental School air 6, fire 6, wood 4

So, do I use the tags from the school, or the tags from the elemental school? If I choose [Air](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/elemental-arcane-schools/air/) and my opposition school was [Fire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/elemental-arcane-schools/fire) what do I do?

Comment: Bad example; Air opposes Earth, you don't get to choose a different opposition school. The question is legit, though, since [Geyser](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/geyser) [fire, water] raises the same issue.

Comment: I was trying to remember the name of the fire water spell, that was it, Geyser.

Comment: @topquark I had based the opposition off the element void page and the normal arcane schools where you just choose, I had not read the small little elemental page which tells us what the opposition schools are until now. So thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I would treat it as both

You gain all benefits of your elemental school, but must prepare the spell using two spell slots. There are no developer commentary on this and searching the message boards provided no insight on the topic, but I would personally interpret that the spell qualifies as both schools, your favourite school and your opposite school, something rare but that exist in the vast list of wizard spells.

There are other spells like this, like [Trial of Fire and Acid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/trial-of-fire-and-acid/), [World Wave](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/world-wave/) and [Geyser](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/geyser/). But note that out of these, only *Geyser* actually qualifies as both your elemental school and your opposed school, as you dont get to choose which elements are opposed, those are already defined. Water opposed fire and air opposes acid.

For spells that can be of multiple descriptors and the element is chosen at the time of casting, such as [Elemental Aura](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-aura/), I would let it be prepared in a single slot, but you would only be able to select the opposition element at time of casting if it was prepared using two slots.

But this penalty can be fixed at 9th level by taking [Opposition Research](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries/arcane-discoveries-paizo/opposition-research/).